# What do the cherry blossom petals mean when they surround an enemy?

Tags: rogue-legacy

I hate myself for not getting a screen cap of it, but in the forest, there was a Icen with cherry blossoms floating all around it, for no apparent reason.

I killed it without thinking, before being able to take any sort of screenshot to show it off.

What does this special effect on an enemy signify?

Comment: Icen come surrounded with icicles. But I'm guessing what you saw was pink?

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't an Earth Wizard (Earthsor, Gravisor, Terrasor) that you saw? They are surrounded by a cherry blossom like effect.

Comment: @MattEllen That's probably what it was.  I never noticed it before, and I killed it so quickly I couldn't really check to find out what it was.  Heck, I never even noticed the particle effect before until last night.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like it was said in comments, some enemies are surrounded by cherry blossom. It can be seen on their tables, when you finish the game.

[image: Earthsor]
[image: Gravisor]
[image: Terrasor]

It exists other enemies that are surrounded with ice also (the blue one which throw pikes ice, don't remember the name).